# Consulta datos repetidos MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo 3 tablas con distintos datos para cada una, a la hora de visualizar los datos para las dos primeras tablas se ven bien y ordenados, pero cuando aparece la 3 tabla, se visualiza mal porque  la primera fila de datos de la tercera tabla se repite muchas veces y no permite ver los demás datos, que puedo hacer?

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| fecha_entrega_1_1 | fecha_entrega_2_2 | fecha_entrega_3_3 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2019-08-31        | 2019-12-07        | 2019-05-11        |
| 2020-09-20        | 2020-09-20        | 2019-05-11        |
| NULL              | NULL              | 2019-05-11        |
| 0000-00-00        | 0000-00-00        | 2019-05-11        |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Las dos primeras tablas se ven bien, pero la 3 no, aquí están los datos:

```
CREATE TABLE CERCEDILLA_3_3
(enlace VARCHAR (40),
fecha_recogida_3_3 DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
fecha_entrega_3_3 DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
hermano VARCHAR (30),
CONSTRAINT PK_CERCEDILLA_3_3 PRIMARY KEY (enlace),
CONSTRAINT FK_CERCEDILLA_3_ENLACE FOREIGN KEY (enlace) REFERENCES CERCEDILLA_1_1 (enlace));

INSERT INTO CERCEDILLA_3_3 (fecha_recogida_3_3,fecha_entrega_3_3,hermano,enlace)
VALUES 
('2018-12-22', '2019-05-11', 'Paola Jimenez', 1), 
('2019-06-01', '2019-09-10', 'Rut Jimenez', 2), 
('2019-11-19', '2020-12-18', 'Tania Alvala', 3),
('2021-01-10', NULL, 'Paula Alvaro', 4),
('0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', NULL, 5),
('0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', NULL, 6),
('0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', NULL, 7);
```

Y esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.fecha_entrega_1_1, b.fecha_entrega_2_2, c.fecha_entrega_3_3
FROM CERCEDILLA_1_1 a, CERCEDILLA_2_2 b, CERCEDILLA_3_3 c
WHERE a.enlace = b.enlace = c.enlace;
```

Me podríais ayudar?

Comment: como mejoro el formato??